# Pass data between different "Via" Laravel Notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Do you know how to pass data between 2 different "Via" notification?
This is the situation:
I have created 2 custom channels for notification

1. PushNotificationChannel
2. CustomDatabase

In my Notification Class I have this:

```
class GeneralNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $notificationType;
    private $sender;

    public function __construct($notificationType, $sender)
    {
        $this->notificationType = $notificationType;
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [CustomDatabaseChannel::class, PushNotificationChannel::class];
    }

    public function toPushNotification($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }


    public function toCustomDatabase($notifiable)
    {
       return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

So this will first execute the `toCustomDatabase` method, and then the `toPushNotification` method.

What I want is after I save the data into de database, pass it (the inserted record) to the `toPushNotification` method.

I was testing with assigning for example:

```
public function toCustomDatabase($notifiable)
    {
       $this->notificationType = 'test';
       return [
            //
        ];
    }
```

but when I do:

```
public function toPushNotification($notifiable)
    {
        dd($this->notificationType);
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
```

It shows me the original notificationType, and not the value I changed in the `toCustomDatabase` method.

Comment: It's probably because the notification object is being serialized before queued, with both 'via' methods using the original serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to add the inserted record into de `session()` (Although in API Middleware the session is not persistent, it works within the request cycle). Then in the `toPushNoification` method I retreive that session.